# how to confirm the format of a field in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to check the existing fields that are returned from an sql query are in a specified format. Returning any fields that are not in any of the 4 defined formats.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I don't currently have any code, as not sure where to start with this.

The formats I need to check are listed below.

```
(1) AB0161298 [ ie 9 chars] 
(2) AB0161298002 [ie 12 chars] 
(3) ABC - AB0161298 [ie 15 chars] 
(4) ABC - AB0161298002 [ie 18 chars]
```

Hope you can help, or give some advice.

Many thanks

Comment: you can use regular expressions for that

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE will work here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

Comment: To start you along the way: If you need to display the values that do not conform to your models, you can use `select field_name where not regexp_like(field_name, <match_pattern>)`. The match pattern is a string (enclosed in `'...'`); it should match the entire field, so it should begin with `^` and end with `$` to anchor both at the beginning and the end of the string; and otherwise it should have the structure `(....|....|....|....)` where the `....` are the four 'good' patterns. `'^(....|....|....|....)$'` Please write back if you need more help.

Comment: If the difference is purely length of field, use len(field) to get the length of it and go from there.

Comment: Thank you all - reg expressions worked, just one other question which is more of a hindrance than actual issue, if anyone is able to help, its posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below to return the formats that should not exist, worked fine. Thanks for all your help.

```
select * from table where field NOT IN 
( select field from table
where regexp_like(field,'^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9] [-] [A-Z0-9]{9}$') 
OR regexp_like(field,'^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9] [-] [A-Z0-9]{12}$') OR 
regexp_like(field,'^[A-Z0-9]{9}$') OR regexp_like(field,'^
[[A-Z0-9]{12}$'));
```

Only question I have now is it has returned thousands of different fields (most of the same format, meaning only 1 or 2 additional formats) but is there anyway of displaying only distinct formats? to get a list of a few rather than thousands?

Answer (score -1):

---try this one

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'table_name'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position
```

Comment: He/She does not want to check if the columns are there, but if the value *in* the columns complies with a certain pattern. Plus: Oracle has no `information_schema`